# how to retrieve single data from Room database in android and display it in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am learning Android. I want to retrieve a specific row of data using the Room database and display it in a text view after clicking the button in Fragment. Here is some source code. Please help me to sort it out.

```
  @Entity(tableName = "Engine_List")

  public class Engin_Entity
   {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int engn_id;

private String str_DUE_AGMTNO;
private String str_CustomerName;
private int POS_NO;
private String str_REG_NUM;
private String str_ChassisNo;
private String str_ENG_NO;
private String str_Model_No;
private int first_ContactNo;
private String first_ContactName;
private int second_ContactNo;
private String second_ContactName;

}
```

in Dao class

```
//View specific row details
@Query("SELECT * FROM Engine_List WHERE CHASSIS_NO = :CHASSIS_NO" )
       Engin_Entity findSpecific_ChassisNo(String CHASSIS_NO);
```

In Fragment Class

```
  public class Fragment_RegistrationDetail extends Fragment
 {

private Engin_Entity engin_entity;
private Database_ENGN database_Engine;
private EnginList_Dao enginListDao;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__search_page, container, false);

    database_Engine = Database_ENGN.getEngnDatabase(getContext());

    List<Engin_Entity> engin_entity = database_Engine.engineList_Dao().
               findSpecific_ChassisNo(engin_entity.getStr_ChassisNo());

}


}
```

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: Yeah, though to know when we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Actually, in Fragment, i don't know how to display the data in fragments in text view.